# Thermocouple signal conditioning - how to deal with low output swing margin of amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, output, instrumentation-amplifier, dc-offset

[image]

I have this thermocouple conditioning circuit. Let's say my gain is 100. Minimum low  level for [AD8237](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8237.pdf) is 20mV. As K type thermocouple outputs 40uV per 1C, I will have 4mV per 1 degree C.

This means I will not see change on the output while temperature goes from ambient to ambient + 5C.

Suppose, I don't want to loose these 5 degrees at the bottom of my range. What do I do? I think, I have to inject some offset into the +IN input? If so, how do I do it? What are the other possibilities?

I would like to avoid using split supply.

Comment: No cold compensation?  No ESD protection?  Maxim IC and others have chips with thermocouple in, SPI or I2C out.  ADI has precision amps made for thermocouple in with cold compensation included (and lots of good app notes).  I would use one of these options rather than roll my own.

Comment: cold junction compensation is performed digitally, i'm aware of all the different integrated options, this is more like an excercise to deal with the basics and maybe achieve better performance for less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the 20mv error is a measure of how close the output can go to 0v (using your supplies) against a 100 kilohm load pulling the output to "mid-supply" i.e. 2.5V.

Without that pull-up, as in your application, the output will go considerably closer to 0V.

However if you need to inject offset; the place to do it is "ref" i.e. pin 6 - whatever voltage is there, is the "0V" reference point for the output.

Note also that the thermocouple will ONLY generate 0V at ambient if it is actually a pair of thermocouples; connected back to back, one measuring the temperature of interest, the other being held at ambient (or 0C or some known point) to act as a "cold reference". (This may be what your "thermocouple" does, but its worth mentioning because the circuit doesn't show it).

Otherwise you have at least three thermocouples in the circuit; two of them being unknown quantities, formed by the connector pins. In which case the actual voltage is anybody's guess.

One further point - I see you connect the thermocouple via a connector. It's worth considering what happens when unplugged : I recommend a high value resistor from `-in` to `+in` to prevent `+in` floating. (1 megohm with the 1na bias current implies an offset of 1 mv with no thermocouple, and it will have no measurable effect with the thermocouple present)

Comment: I'm aware of thermocouple effect being introduced by connections of different metals in connectors and i'm doing cold junction compensation digitally, I was just puzzled by this margin and totally forgot about the ref pin, silly me :)